# How to write output with new lines in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create a Powershell script that looks for a certain string in file contents.

Here is my `script.ps1`

```
$lookup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the word you're looking for:"
$res = sls "$lookup" (dir -Recurse *.txt, *.docx, *xlsx)
Write-output "$res"

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Looking for a string "A" from my test directory.
The output is below:

```
Enter the word youre looking for: A
C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test1.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test2.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test3.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test4.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
Press Enter to exit:
```

I would like to have a following output with new lines.
How do I get the output like this?

```
Enter the word youre looking for: A
C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test1.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test2.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test3.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
C:\Users\koyamashinji\Downloads\test\test4.txt:1:ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
Press Enter to exit:
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes from the "$res" variable:

```
$lookup = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the word you're looking for:"
$res = sls "$lookup" (dir -Recurse *.txt, *.docx, *xlsx)
Write-output $res  <--------- HERE

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```